# jQuery use an object's method as an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, event-handling, jquery-events

I have an object. It initializes a button to alert "Hello!" when it is clicked. Why won't this work?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUT52/1/

HTML

```
<button>Test</button>
```

JS

```
var MyObject = {
  testValue: "Hello!",

  testFunction: function() {
    alert(this.testValue);
  },

  init: function(button) {
    button.click(this.testFunction());
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var buttonInstance = new MyObject();
  var button = $('button');
  buttonInstance.init(button);
});
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense! You can't initialize a new object literal like that. If you want to use `new` and treat it like a "constructor", you have to make `MyObject` a function. Otherwise, `MyObject` is an object literal and you can access it statically - `MyObject.testValue`

Comment: Mind blown @Ian. That makes js objects make so much more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever you put `()` behind a function reference, you are **executing** the function. You have to pass the function reference to `.click`, not what the function returns (unless the function returns a function that you want to use as event handler).

Example:

```
button.click(this.testFunction);
```

But now you have another problem: Inside the function, `this` will refer to the DOM element and not to the object, so accessing `this.testValue` will return `undefined`.

You can use jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function to fix this:

```
button.click($.proxy(this.testFunction, this));
```

Now `this` will refer to the object, and you can get a reference to the clicked element via `event.target`.

Answer (score 4):

For two reasons:

- You are using `testFunction()` instead of `testFunction` when you bind the event, so you will be calling the function and binding the (undefined) return value.
- When you use a method as a function, it's no longer attached to the object, so the context will not be the object when the callback is called, but the global `window` object.

Use the `proxy` method to make a function that calls the method with the right context:

```
button.click($.proxy(this.testFunction, this));
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa, is it possible to use .bind(this) instead of $.proxy()?

Comment: @DonnyP Yeah they accomplish the same thing

Comment: @DonnyP: Yes, but that doesn't work in all browsers. That's why `proxy` is there.

Comment: Is the syntax `button.click(this.testFunction.bind(this))` ?

Comment: @Guffa What's funny to me is that jQuery doesn't even bother checking for `Function.prototype.bind`, they just always use their custom way

Comment: So I've got `button.click(this.testFunction.bind(this))`. And how does that differ from `button.on('click', this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))?

Comment: @Ian: It just takes longer to check for different ways of doing it, than to just do it.

Comment: @DonnyP: They are using different methods for the callback, otherwise they do the same thing. Including not working in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

That's an object literal, and you'd normally use it like so :

```
var MyObject = {
    testValue: "Hello!",

    testFunction: function() {
        alert(MyObject.testValue);
    },

    init: function(button) {
        button.on('click', this.testFunction);
    }
}

var button = $('button');
MyObject.init(button);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kUT52/5/)

or passing the object:

```
var MyObject = {
    testValue: "Hello!",

    testFunction: function(e) {
        alert(e.data.obj.testValue);
    },

    init: function(button) {
        button.on('click', {obj: this}, this.testFunction);
    }
}

var button = $('button');
MyObject.init(button);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kUT52/7/)

Comment: Well it got the alert working, but still alerts "undefined" :P

Comment: @DonnyP - didn't notice! That's because wintin the scope of the testFunction, `this` would be the button when called that way, not the object. You either have to reference the object directly, or pass `this` as a parameter.